# WordPress, ACF, CPT - how to control multiple ACF values

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have 3 custom post types:

- team-member
- team-group
- speciality

Each team member have own group and speciality but some of them have a few specialities.
I have successfully outputted here a team member image, name, and speciality but I'm not able to find the way to have a control what speciality is actually outputted on my team member card.
So, in two different locations if the member have assigned more than one speciality they are outputted randomly :( Any help is highly appreciated!

```
$relatedTeamMembers = new WP_Query(array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'team-member',
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'related_team_group',
        'compare' => 'LIKE',
        'value' => '130'
    )
    )
));

if ($relatedTeamMembers->have_posts()) {
    echo '<div class="team-members__wrapper">';
        while($relatedTeamMembers->have_posts()) {
            $relatedTeamMembers->the_post(); ?>
                <div class="team-member">
                    <div class="overlay-button">
                        <img class="team-member__image" src="<?php
                            if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
                                the_post_thumbnail_url('teamMemberPortrait');
                                } else {
                                echo get_theme_file_uri('img/placeholder.png');
                        } ?> ">
                    </div>
                    <div class="team-member__label">
                        <div class="team-member__label__name"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
                        <div class="team-member__label__speciality"><?php
                            $specialities = get_field('related_speciality');
                            foreach($specialities as $specialities);
                            echo $specialities->post_title; ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        <?php }
    echo '</div>';
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: $specialities is field, not post. Why you try to get post_title?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply but no, `speciality` is a custom post type same as `team-member` or `team-group`. `$specialities` is a variable. And post_title gives me speciality name outputted at the ech member's card according to relationships set in ACF.